# How to display int values in a textfield?

Tags: c#, winforms, textfield

I am developing a web forms app in Visual Studio, and I am trying to build an update grid.

I can bring in the `string` values from a record but am having trouble when it comes to bring in the `int` values as in this case of `Age`.

I have posted my code below.

Code:

```
private void DisplayPersonData(Author p)
{
    txtFName.Text = p.Name;
    txtAge.Text = p.Age;//Problem is here 
}

protected void btnSearchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
    hfId.Value = id.ToString();
    targetPerson = GetPersonById(id);
    DisplayPersonData(targetPerson);
}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    targetPerson = GetPersonById(Convert.ToInt32(hfId.Value));
    targetPerson.Name = txtFName.Text;
    targetPerson.Age = txtAge.Text;//Problem is here 

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am thinking I need to convert the `int` to a `string`, but I am not sure how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert to int when you save and convert back to string when you set the value,

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        targetPerson = GetPersonById(Convert.ToInt32(hfId.Value));
        targetPerson.Name = txtFName.Text;
        targetPerson.Age =  Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and

```
private void DisplayPersonData(Author p)
    {
        txtFName.Text = p.Name;
        txtAge.Text = p.Age.ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly I knew it had something to do with converting the int to a string just didnt know how to right it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***ToString()*** method to convert the age integer value to string as shown below:

```
txtAge.Text = p.Age.ToString();
```

Or you can eve do the following:

```
txtAge.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Age);
```

Moreover, if you need to further use it for calculations  then you will have to convert it back to Integer and that you can do by following:

```
Int32 Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
```

For further details, you can go visit [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/cast) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_type_conversion.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

```
txtAge.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Age);
targetPerson.Age = Convert.ToString(txtAge.Text);
```

or

```
txtAge.Text = "" + p.Age;
targetPerson.Age = ""+ txtAge.Text;
```

or

```
txtAge.Text = p.Age.ToString();
targetPerson.Age = txtAge.Text.ToString();
```